# Better way to rewrite method without deprecated JRequest

Tags: joomla-3.x, jrequest, deprecated

I believe JRequest is deprecated in the latest version of Joomla 3, have rewritten this function:

```
public function display($tpl = null)
{
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    
    $this->state = $this->get('State');
    $this->item = $this->get('Data');
    $this->params = $app->getParams('com_car');
    
    $db         =   JFactory::getDBO();
    $user       = JFactory::getUser();
    // Push a model into the view
    $model      = $this->getModel();
    $modelcar   = $this->getModel( 'product' );
    $id = JRequest::getVar('id','','default','int');
    $vid = JRequest::getVar('vid','','default','int');
    
    $prodDet = $modelcar->loadProduct($id,$vid);
    
    $this->assignRef('prodDet'  , $prodDet);
            
    $CatName = $modelcar->getCatName($id);
    $this->assignRef('CatName'  , $CatName);
}
```

*New Code*

```
public function display($tpl = null)
{
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    
    $this->state = $this->get('State');
    $this->item = $this->get('Data');
    $this->params = $app->getParams('com_car');
    
    $db         =   JFactory::getDBO();
    $user       = JFactory::getUser();
    // Push a model into the view
    $model      = $this->getModel();
    $modelcar   = $this->getModel( 'product' );
            
    $jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $id = $jinput->get('id','','default','int');
    $vid = $jinput->get('vid','','default','int');
    
    //  $id = JRequest::getVar('id','','default','int');
    //  $vid = JRequest::getVar('vid','','default','int');
    
    $prodDet = $modelcar->loadProduct($id,$vid);
    
    $this->assignRef('prodDet'  , $prodDet);
            
    $CatName = $modelcar->getCatName($id);
    $this->assignRef('CatName'  , $CatName);
```

Is this the correct fix? Is there a better way to rewrite this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace the use of `JFactory` with a `Factory` to prepare for Joomla 5.0 where it will be depreciated.

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;

class yourclassname
{
   public function display($tpl = null)
    {
    $app = Factory::getApplication()
    ...
    }
   ...
}
```

You could also see if the Application is already available to your class by checking if `$this->app` already exists.

As you have already got the Application with the above assigned to `$app` or `$this->app` then you don't need to get it again with `$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;` , updating your code with these statements  instead.

```
$id  = $app->input->get('id','','default','int');
$vid = $app->input->get('vid','','default','int');
```

or if $this->app is available.

```
$id  = $this->app->input->get('id','','default','int');
$vid = $this->app->input->get('vid','','default','int');
```

These two statements can also be updated to use Factory as well.

```
$db        = Factory::getDBO();
$user      = Factory::getUser();
```

And you have two statements for `$user = JFactory::getUser();`, you only need to get it once.

Comment: Thanks but somehow without Jfactory causing error, so as of now has to use Jfactory but am marking your reply for future save as and when upgrade in then can remove it with factory,. However thanks yes 2 statements were for $user

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using? I assumed you are using a fairly recent version of Joomla 3.x. And what is the error message you are getting when you try to use Factory?

Comment: Hi its 3.10 n php 8 - getting this error - 0 - syntax error, unexpected token "use"

Comment: On enabling debugging found an issue due to controller.php

Comment: `code`public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)
 {
  use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
  $db        = Factory::getDBO();
        $user      = Factory::getUser();
  
  $view = Factory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('view', 'categories');
  Factory::getApplication()->input->set('view', $view);

  parent::display($cachable, $urlparams);

  return $this;
 }

Comment: The Use statement needs to appear before your Class statement, you appear to have placed it inside a function called display. I have updated the answer to make it clearer where to place the use statement. If you look at pretty much any piece of core code you will see examples of how it should be placed.

Comment: thanks. yes it worked perfectly. Appreciate help. Just for learning purpose, as you specified that same will be used in joomla 5.0 - will this still impact the code in 3.10 or joomla 4 with quicker processing or its just the name change.

Comment: There maybe some form of performance improvement but that is not really the reason for the changes but it is more than just a name change. There has been a move away from the J prefixed methods for sometime in Joomla 3 and with Joomla 4 it introduces changes in the way we build extension moving to a Dependency Injection or Service Locater which in general is a good thing, but there is lots to learn.